# How to keep attributes for an object in javascript if they have a specific key/value

Tags: javascript

I have an api call response with this format.
They are token and I know how to filter an array.
But here instead of an array I have an object.

```
{
  "AFjQbjBwEF4HfBgKYTeK3SZg4cGRuB9o3rNGmQvHwtFX": {
    "name": "000# Heartbreak",
    "symbol": "NNPOSTER",
    "description": "The crystal broken heart is a mirror through which residents of the NEONEXUS can take a peek into the real world as we know it.",
    "seller_fee_basis_points": 500,
    "image": "https://arweave.net/8TpUvw7hi7N_rVuG6avV_cOX2bXQ7OsY-ZNtILCM-zo?ext=jpg",
    "animation_url": "https://arweave.net/WdzVw-_XE7LQArXArYJNpeMSgFbYYwa1ATpCVrfrTK8?ext=mp4",
    "external_url": "https://neonexus.io",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "trait_type": "City",
        "value": "Miami"
      },
      {
        "trait_type": "Theme",
        "value": "Heartbreak in Miami"
      },
      {
        "trait_type": "Origin",
        "value": "Airdrop"
      },
      {
        "trait_type": "Scene",
        "value": "Moody"
      },
      {
        "trait_type": "Period",
        "value": "Lockdown"
      },
      {
        "trait_type": "Artist",
        "value": "Daramola"
      }
    ],
    "collection": {
      "name": "NEONEXUS Posters",
      "family": "Raynesfere"
    },
    "properties": {
      "files": [
        {
          "uri": "https://arweave.net/8TpUvw7hi7N_rVuG6avV_cOX2bXQ7OsY-ZNtILCM-zo?ext=jpg",
          "type": "image/gif"
        },
        {
          "uri": "https://arweave.net/WdzVw-_XE7LQArXArYJNpeMSgFbYYwa1ATpCVrfrTK8?ext=mp4",
          "type": "video/mp4"
        }
      ],
      "category": "video",
      "creators": [
        {
          "address": "Ef896VQS1tfMACgL5Ce1TR7JZhehkrtowCyZZyYv7SWn",
          "share": 100
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "F8EeyxkR5EBs7ALaapV2jNos8jdbdgpqjtEaJ6fVfB3K": {
    "name": "Skellies #4107",
    "symbol": "SKULL",
    "description": "Skellies is a collection of 8888 spooky skeletons presented by the SolSocks team",
    "seller_fee_basis_points": 500,
    "image": "https://www.arweave.net/mG5dY4GC-3g9j661NRQWoGYWKUtbqDvfhW8whDVVEF0?ext=png",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "trait_type": "Background",
        "value": "Pepto"
      },
      {
        "trait_type": "Skin",
        "value": "Purple Haze"
      },
      {
        "trait_type": "Eyes",
        "value": "Angry"
      },
      {
        "trait_type": "Nose",
        "value": "Double Double"
      },
      {
        "trait_type": "Chest",
        "value": "None"
      },
      {
        "trait_type": "Ears",
        "value": "none"
      },
      {
        "trait_type": "Mouth",
        "value": "WGMI #2"
      },
      {
        "trait_type": "Glasses",
        "value": "none"
      },
      {
        "trait_type": "Headwear",
        "value": "Droid"
      },
      {
        "trait_type": "Limited Edition",
        "value": "no"
      },
      {
        "trait_type": "Dna",
        "value": "82310019050"
      }
    ],
    "collection": {
      "name": "Skellies X SolSocks",
      "family": "Skellies"
    },
    "properties": {
      "files": [
        {
          "uri": "https://www.arweave.net/mG5dY4GC-3g9j661NRQWoGYWKUtbqDvfhW8whDVVEF0?ext=png",
          "type": "image/png"
        }
      ],
      "category": "image",
      "creators": [
        {
          "address": "CpvHujvbSJ9btvPmP5FUKC8QpGM8AQjFk7uLJSsomoH2",
          "share": 85
        },
        {
          "address": "BQ6FxfRVDWKUVeqD9uHFqBjebJ9Um8RVzPTPZ1bBoByU",
          "share": 15
        }
      ]
    }
  },
}
```

I need to keep only the tokens with a specific `collection.name`: "Skellies X SolSocks".
I cannot use map because is an object.
Is there a map/filter/reduce function I can use?

Comment: [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) or [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) should be able to help you get something you can filter in the usual ways.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), to get an array of the objects key/value pairs.

We can then use `Array.filter()` to filter by any property, in this case name, then we can use `Object.fromEntries()` to create the desired result.

```js
let obj = { "AFjQbjBwEF4HfBgKYTeK3SZg4cGRuB9o3rNGmQvHwtFX": { "name": "000# Heartbreak", "symbol": "NNPOSTER", "description": "The crystal broken heart is a mirror through which residents of the NEONEXUS can take a peek into the real world as we know it.", "seller_fee_basis_points": 500, "image": "https://arweave.net/8TpUvw7hi7N_rVuG6avV_cOX2bXQ7OsY-ZNtILCM-zo?ext=jpg", "animation_url": "https://arweave.net/WdzVw-_XE7LQArXArYJNpeMSgFbYYwa1ATpCVrfrTK8?ext=mp4", "external_url": "https://neonexus.io", "attributes": [ { "trait_type": "City", "value": "Miami" }, { "trait_type": "Theme", "value": "Heartbreak in Miami" }, { "trait_type": "Origin", "value": "Airdrop" }, { "trait_type": "Scene", "value": "Moody" }, { "trait_type": "Period", "value": "Lockdown" }, { "trait_type": "Artist", "value": "Daramola" } ], "collection": { "name": "NEONEXUS Posters", "family": "Raynesfere" }, "properties": { "files": [ { "uri": "https://arweave.net/8TpUvw7hi7N_rVuG6avV_cOX2bXQ7OsY-ZNtILCM-zo?ext=jpg", "type": "image/gif" }, { "uri": "https://arweave.net/WdzVw-_XE7LQArXArYJNpeMSgFbYYwa1ATpCVrfrTK8?ext=mp4", "type": "video/mp4" } ], "category": "video", "creators": [ { "address": "Ef896VQS1tfMACgL5Ce1TR7JZhehkrtowCyZZyYv7SWn", "share": 100 } ] } }, "F8EeyxkR5EBs7ALaapV2jNos8jdbdgpqjtEaJ6fVfB3K": { "name": "Skellies #4107", "symbol": "SKULL", "description": "Skellies is a collection of 8888 spooky skeletons presented by the SolSocks team", "seller_fee_basis_points": 500, "image": "https://www.arweave.net/mG5dY4GC-3g9j661NRQWoGYWKUtbqDvfhW8whDVVEF0?ext=png", "attributes": [ { "trait_type": "Background", "value": "Pepto" }, { "trait_type": "Skin", "value": "Purple Haze" }, { "trait_type": "Eyes", "value": "Angry" }, { "trait_type": "Nose", "value": "Double Double" }, { "trait_type": "Chest", "value": "None" }, { "trait_type": "Ears", "value": "none" }, { "trait_type": "Mouth", "value": "WGMI #2" }, { "trait_type": "Glasses", "value": "none" }, { "trait_type": "Headwear", "value": "Droid" }, { "trait_type": "Limited Edition", "value": "no" }, { "trait_type": "Dna", "value": "82310019050" } ], "collection": { "name": "Skellies X SolSocks", "family": "Skellies" }, "properties": { "files": [ { "uri": "https://www.arweave.net/mG5dY4GC-3g9j661NRQWoGYWKUtbqDvfhW8whDVVEF0?ext=png", "type": "image/png" } ], "category": "image", "creators": [ { "address": "CpvHujvbSJ9btvPmP5FUKC8QpGM8AQjFk7uLJSsomoH2", "share": 85 }, { "address": "BQ6FxfRVDWKUVeqD9uHFqBjebJ9Um8RVzPTPZ1bBoByU", "share": 15 } ] } }, }

const searchTerm = 'Skellies';
const result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([key, val]) => { 
    return val.name.includes(searchTerm);
}));
console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

You could also try a [for .. in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop to iterate over the object keys, adding any child objects with a matching name value.

```js
let obj = { "AFjQbjBwEF4HfBgKYTeK3SZg4cGRuB9o3rNGmQvHwtFX": { "name": "000# Heartbreak", "symbol": "NNPOSTER", "description": "The crystal broken heart is a mirror through which residents of the NEONEXUS can take a peek into the real world as we know it.", "seller_fee_basis_points": 500, "image": "https://arweave.net/8TpUvw7hi7N_rVuG6avV_cOX2bXQ7OsY-ZNtILCM-zo?ext=jpg", "animation_url": "https://arweave.net/WdzVw-_XE7LQArXArYJNpeMSgFbYYwa1ATpCVrfrTK8?ext=mp4", "external_url": "https://neonexus.io", "attributes": [ { "trait_type": "City", "value": "Miami" }, { "trait_type": "Theme", "value": "Heartbreak in Miami" }, { "trait_type": "Origin", "value": "Airdrop" }, { "trait_type": "Scene", "value": "Moody" }, { "trait_type": "Period", "value": "Lockdown" }, { "trait_type": "Artist", "value": "Daramola" } ], "collection": { "name": "NEONEXUS Posters", "family": "Raynesfere" }, "properties": { "files": [ { "uri": "https://arweave.net/8TpUvw7hi7N_rVuG6avV_cOX2bXQ7OsY-ZNtILCM-zo?ext=jpg", "type": "image/gif" }, { "uri": "https://arweave.net/WdzVw-_XE7LQArXArYJNpeMSgFbYYwa1ATpCVrfrTK8?ext=mp4", "type": "video/mp4" } ], "category": "video", "creators": [ { "address": "Ef896VQS1tfMACgL5Ce1TR7JZhehkrtowCyZZyYv7SWn", "share": 100 } ] } }, "F8EeyxkR5EBs7ALaapV2jNos8jdbdgpqjtEaJ6fVfB3K": { "name": "Skellies #4107", "symbol": "SKULL", "description": "Skellies is a collection of 8888 spooky skeletons presented by the SolSocks team", "seller_fee_basis_points": 500, "image": "https://www.arweave.net/mG5dY4GC-3g9j661NRQWoGYWKUtbqDvfhW8whDVVEF0?ext=png", "attributes": [ { "trait_type": "Background", "value": "Pepto" }, { "trait_type": "Skin", "value": "Purple Haze" }, { "trait_type": "Eyes", "value": "Angry" }, { "trait_type": "Nose", "value": "Double Double" }, { "trait_type": "Chest", "value": "None" }, { "trait_type": "Ears", "value": "none" }, { "trait_type": "Mouth", "value": "WGMI #2" }, { "trait_type": "Glasses", "value": "none" }, { "trait_type": "Headwear", "value": "Droid" }, { "trait_type": "Limited Edition", "value": "no" }, { "trait_type": "Dna", "value": "82310019050" } ], "collection": { "name": "Skellies X SolSocks", "family": "Skellies" }, "properties": { "files": [ { "uri": "https://www.arweave.net/mG5dY4GC-3g9j661NRQWoGYWKUtbqDvfhW8whDVVEF0?ext=png", "type": "image/png" } ], "category": "image", "creators": [ { "address": "CpvHujvbSJ9btvPmP5FUKC8QpGM8AQjFk7uLJSsomoH2", "share": 85 }, { "address": "BQ6FxfRVDWKUVeqD9uHFqBjebJ9Um8RVzPTPZ1bBoByU", "share": 15 } ] } }, }
 
const result = {};
const searchTerm = 'Skellies';

for(let k in obj) {
    if (obj[k] && ((obj[k].name || "").includes(searchTerm))) {
        result[k] = obj[k];
    }
}
console.log('Result:', result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a `for` loop  to loop over the object's entries:

```js
const yourObject = {"AFjQbjBwEF4HfBgKYTeK3SZg4cGRuB9o3rNGmQvHwtFX":{"name":"000# Heartbreak","symbol":"NNPOSTER","description":"The crystal broken heart is a mirror through which residents of the NEONEXUS can take a peek into the real world as we know it.","seller_fee_basis_points":500,"image":"https://arweave.net/8TpUvw7hi7N_rVuG6avV_cOX2bXQ7OsY-ZNtILCM-zo?ext=jpg","animation_url":"https://arweave.net/WdzVw-_XE7LQArXArYJNpeMSgFbYYwa1ATpCVrfrTK8?ext=mp4","external_url":"https://neonexus.io","attributes":[{"trait_type":"City","value":"Miami"},{"trait_type":"Theme","value":"Heartbreak in Miami"},{"trait_type":"Origin","value":"Airdrop"},{"trait_type":"Scene","value":"Moody"},{"trait_type":"Period","value":"Lockdown"},{"trait_type":"Artist","value":"Daramola"}],"collection":{"name":"NEONEXUS Posters","family":"Raynesfere"},"properties":{"files":[{"uri":"https://arweave.net/8TpUvw7hi7N_rVuG6avV_cOX2bXQ7OsY-ZNtILCM-zo?ext=jpg","type":"image/gif"},{"uri":"https://arweave.net/WdzVw-_XE7LQArXArYJNpeMSgFbYYwa1ATpCVrfrTK8?ext=mp4","type":"video/mp4"}],"category":"video","creators":[{"address":"Ef896VQS1tfMACgL5Ce1TR7JZhehkrtowCyZZyYv7SWn","share":100}]}},"F8EeyxkR5EBs7ALaapV2jNos8jdbdgpqjtEaJ6fVfB3K":{"name":"Skellies #4107","symbol":"SKULL","description":"Skellies is a collection of 8888 spooky skeletons presented by the SolSocks team","seller_fee_basis_points":500,"image":"https://www.arweave.net/mG5dY4GC-3g9j661NRQWoGYWKUtbqDvfhW8whDVVEF0?ext=png","attributes":[{"trait_type":"Background","value":"Pepto"},{"trait_type":"Skin","value":"Purple Haze"},{"trait_type":"Eyes","value":"Angry"},{"trait_type":"Nose","value":"Double Double"},{"trait_type":"Chest","value":"None"},{"trait_type":"Ears","value":"none"},{"trait_type":"Mouth","value":"WGMI #2"},{"trait_type":"Glasses","value":"none"},{"trait_type":"Headwear","value":"Droid"},{"trait_type":"Limited Edition","value":"no"},{"trait_type":"Dna","value":"82310019050"}],"collection":{"name":"Skellies X SolSocks","family":"Skellies"},"properties":{"files":[{"uri":"https://www.arweave.net/mG5dY4GC-3g9j661NRQWoGYWKUtbqDvfhW8whDVVEF0?ext=png","type":"image/png"}],"category":"image","creators":[{"address":"CpvHujvbSJ9btvPmP5FUKC8QpGM8AQjFk7uLJSsomoH2","share":85},{"address":"BQ6FxfRVDWKUVeqD9uHFqBjebJ9Um8RVzPTPZ1bBoByU","share":15}]}}};


const tokens = [];
const filteredObject = {};

for (let [token, entry] of Object.entries(yourObject)) {
    if (entry.collection.name === 'Skellies X SolSocks') {
        tokens.push(token);
        filteredObject[token] = entry;
    }
}

console.log(tokens);
console.log(filteredObject);
```